# No me llega el dato al controlador. ¿Que me falta?

Tags: c#, ajax, angularjs

El funcionamiento que necesito de este es cuando selecciono la opcion magnitud que es "8" me traiga de la base de datos las unidades que tengan como magnitud 8.
Ejm: Si selecciono en select1 Brasil que en select2 me traiga municipios de solo Brasil

La validación Ajax me llega al controlador cuando selecciono la magnitud pero me llega vacío.
Quien me ayuda con esto por favor.
Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
//CONTROLADOR
     [HttpGet]
            [Route("consultarMagnitud")]
            public async Task<JsonResult> PostConsultar(byte magnitud)
            {
                ResponseE<MagnitudE> item = await _sGEHelper.ConsultarMagnitud(magnitud);
                return Json(item);
            }
    
    
    //VALIDACION AJAX
         $('#Magnitud').change(function () {
            var url = "/SistemaGE/consultarMagnitud?magnitud" + $('#Magnitud value:selected').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'consultarMagnitud',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    var magnitud;
                    if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
                        magnitud = JSON.parse(result);
                    }
                    if (magnitud != null) {
                        $('#Unidad').val(magnitud.unidad);
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error al consultar datos");
                }
            });
        })
    
    
    //HTML
     <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Magnitud:</label>
                                                <select id="Magnitud" name="Magnitud" class="form-control searchItems" ng-model="sge.Magnitud">
                                                    <option value="0">Seleccione una Opción</option>
                                                    <option value="8">Agua Potable</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Unidad:</label>
                                                <select id="Unidad" name="Unidad" class="form-control searchItems" ng-model="sge.Unidad">
                                                    <optio></optio>
                                                </select>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div
```

Comment: Primero, poner de titulo eso... pon un titulo descriptivo de tu problema mejor.

Comment: Has probado a cambiar PostConsultar por consultarMagnitud?

Comment: Por qué `PostConsultar(byte magnitud)` recibe un byte? No debería ser int? Sabes si `.ConsultarMagnitud()` devuelve datos? Así no se agregan elementos a un select: `$('#Unidad').val(magnitud.unidad);`, por favor investiga o abre otra pregunta.

Comment: @NicolasOñate Si, y aún así no me funciona :(

Answer (score 1):

Despues del parametro magnitud te falta un igual

```
var url = "/SistemaGE/consultarMagnitud?magnitud=" + $('#Magnitud value:selected').val();
```

Nada mas como recomendación, ¿Estas seguro que `$('#Magnitud value:selected').val()` devuelve un tipo byte? (El controlador espera un byte)